# Selecting primary and secondary options by clicking on images

Tags: javascript, vue.js, user-interface, vuejs2, vue-component

My goal is for the user to select two objects, to be placed in primary and secondary spots. Similar to how FB and Instagram deals with selecting images for a post. Ideally they can just tap/ click on one then two, and be able to deselect one by clicking/ tapping that one again.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h3>Pick your two favorite dogs!</h3>
        <div v-for="dog in options" :key="dog.id">
            <a @click="selectFirstThenSecond(dog)" :style="{ isSelected }">
                <img :src="dog.img">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                primaryChoice: '',
                secondaryChoice: '',
                options: [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        name: 'Chihuahua',
                        size: 'Small',
                        img: 'chi.jpg'
                    },
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        name: 'Yorkshire Terrior',
                        size: 'Small',
                        img: 'yorkie.jpg'
                    },
                    {
                        id: 3,
                        name: 'Mastiff',
                        size: 'Large',
                        img: 'mastiff.jpg'
                    },
                    {
                        id: 4,
                        name: 'Brittany Spaniel',
                        size: 'Medium',
                        img: 'brit.jpg'
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        methods: {
            selectFirstThenSecond(dog) {
                ???
            }
        }      
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding an additional parameter to each entry and use that to record your primary and secondary.

```
options: [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Chihuahua',
    size: 'Small',
    img: 'chi.jpg',
    slot: null
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Yorkshire Terrior',
    size: 'Small',
    img: 'yorkie.jpg',
    slot: null
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Mastiff',
    size: 'Large',
    img: 'mastiff.jpg',
    slot: null
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Brittany Spaniel',
    size: 'Medium',
    img: 'brit.jpg',
    slot: null
  }
]
```

Then when you click on each option, your method can either populate that new parameter or set it back to null (to deselect).

```
methods: {
  toggle (option) {
    if (option.slot) { // turn it back off
      option.slot == null;
    } else {
      /* you'll want to pay closer attention to how you set 
         this in case they deactivate the primary after having
         set the secondary. This is just a quick and dirty way to 
         indicate primary vs secondary. */
      option.slot = this.slotsTaken()+1; 
    }
  }
}
```

You can then determine whether both slots have been taken with a computed property.

```
computed: {
  slotsTaken () {
    return this.options.filter(option => slot != null).length;
  }
}
```

Modify things to suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you! This is making sense, only question beyond this is how to access those selected options once they're selected. ie storing them as 'primaryChoice' and 'secondaryChoice' for an ajax request. Also how to limit user choices to only two

Comment: You could define all that in your `toggle` function. I.e. if you are setting an option as active, you could simultaneously update the `primaryChoice` parameter at the same time.  The same thing for your limit - you could check if the `slotsTaken()` value is equal to your max (2) and either stop action, or pop a msg, etc.